# const std::array<char>をEigen::VectorXfに変換する方法は？

Tags: c++, c++11

`const std::array<char>`型で与えられた入力を、`Eigen::VectorXf`型に変換したかったのですが、Eigen::Mapなどを使っても、うまいことやる方法が見当たらず、結局
`for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++) vec(i) = arr[i];`
としました。

あまりきれいなコードではないので、後学のため、よりスマートに書く方法があれば、ご教示下さい。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::array<char>` 型から直接 `Eigen::VectorXf` 型への変換はできない様ですので、一旦、`std::vector<float>` 型へ変換する方法はどうでしょうか。

```
const std::array<char, 4> arr = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

std::vector<float> v(arr.data(), arr.data()+arr.size());
Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXf> vec(v.data(), v.size());

std::cout << vec << std::endl;
=>    
 97
 98
 99
100
```

# スマートな方法とは言い難いですが。。

Comment: やはり、直接変換はできないのですね。その方法が綺麗そうです。